# pppd config , how to bring up eth0 automatically?

Tags: linux, networking, ppp

How can i allow ppp daemon bring up eth0 first before connection ? If the ethernet port is down , no connection would be success.
  So i'm putting this into /etc/ppp/peers/dsl , but eth0 won't be brought up through 'pon dsl' command:

```
plugin rp-pppoe.so
eth0
defaultroute
usepeerdns
user "blabla"
noauth
noipdefault
hide-password
debug
```

And from kernel message buffer:

```
error sending pppoe packet: Network is down
```

P.S: And please don't tell me to bring up eth0 at boot time ;-P , it's already set

Comment: pppd itself cannot bring up eth0.  You generally would accomplish this with a post-up type script, but that depends on which distribution you're using.  Can you update your question by telling us which Linux distro you have?

Comment: Sure , i wanted it on both Gentoo Linux and Arch Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a script that will ping and if the result is zero then it should issue the command:
/etc/init.d/net.eth0 start
ifconfig eth0 up
then connect ppp by pon $tunnel
there should be appropriate wait times between command other wise it might not work.